# motion detection and recording video with webcam

Tags: python, camera, video, webcam

I want to record a video with a webcam when a PIR sensor detect motion, I have the `picamera` library installed, can any one help, thank you?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import picamera
import datetime  # new

def get_file_name():  # new
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.h264")

sensor = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state = False

current_state = False

cam = picamera.PiCamera()

while True:

    time.sleep(0.1)

    previous_state = current_state
    current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
    if current_state != previous_state:
        new_state = "HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
        print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, new_state))

        if current_state:
            fileName = get_file_name()  # new
            cam.start_preview()
            cam.start_recording(fileName)  # new
        else:
            cam.stop_preview()
            cam.stop_recording()  # new
```

Comment: Another user and I have cleaned up the content but I can clearly see that the *python* code provided is incomplete - it is truncated just as it would be getting interested in that the last `if current_state:` line would be followed by a command to start recording as a result of the GPIO pin being taken high, presumably by the PIR output signal.  If it was me writing code I want to do something to keep recording until a certain time *after* the GPIO pin goes low again - though that would depend on how the PIR device behaves (does it have its own "hold on" time after it ceases a detection?)

Comment: yes its incomplete i edit it now code with picamera

Comment: You mention you're using a webcam, but the picamera module only works with the [Pi's camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/), not with USB webcams. Can you confirm what sort of camera you're using?

Comment: that program is with picamera but i wan to use a webcam and I don't know haw

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any custom logic, then you could install [`motion`](https://motion-project.github.io/) (`sudo apt install motion`), tweak its config file at `/etc/motion/motion.conf`, and have it record videos in your desired format (mp4, avi, swf, flv, etc..) when a 'motion event' occurs.

If you want movies to be saved to files, then make sure you set:

```
ffmpeg_output_movies on
ffmpeg_video_codec mp4  # can also use other formats
stream_localhost off  # otherwise only localhost connections are allowed
output_pictures off
```

It includes an HTTP MJPG streaming server which you can watch from your browser or hook to specialized webcam apps (see `stream_port` in the config).

You can run your own scripts or commands on certain event hooks. The useful ones are:

- `on_event_start` — fires when motion is detected
- `on_movie_end` — fires after a movie has been created, receives the path of the created video file, meaning you can e.g. automatically email it to yourself or send to a telegram chat.
- `on_camera_lost` — a hook you can use to take action in case something fails, i.e. restart the `motion` service or reboot your rpi.

Getting it to work the way you want involves getting your config right, and googling will return enough results for different scenarios, e.g. like [this one](https://debian-administration.org/article/347/An_Introduction_to_Video_Surveillance_with_%27Motion%27).